# Inline assembly, SSE code gives me an unhandled exception

Tags: c++, visual-c++, assembly

I'm trying to make vector addition using inline assembly and while debugging it line by line, it seems that I get the correct values, but after the function that contains the inline ASM returns its value, it crashes.Here is the entire code:

```
#include <mmintrin.h>
#include <xmmintrin.h>
#include <emmintrin.h>
#include <pmmintrin.h>
#include <tmmintrin.h>
#include <smmintrin.h>
#include <nmmintrin.h>
#include <wmmintrin.h>
#include <immintrin.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

__declspec(align(16)) struct AlignedPackedScalarStorage
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
    float w;

    friend AlignedPackedScalarStorage operator+(const AlignedPackedScalarStorage& l, const AlignedPackedScalarStorage& r)
    {
        AlignedPackedScalarStorage output;

        __asm
        {
            MOV EAX, [l]
            MOV EBX, [r]

            MOVAPS XMM0, [EAX]
            MOVAPS XMM1, [EBX]

            ADDPS XMM0, XMM1
            MOVAPS [output], XMM0
        }

        return(output);
    };
};

struct UnalignedPackedScalarStorage
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
    float w;
};

int main()
{
    AlignedPackedScalarStorage A = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    AlignedPackedScalarStorage B = { 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    AlignedPackedScalarStorage C = { 3, 5, 7, 9 };
    AlignedPackedScalarStorage D = A + B;

    cout << "Non SIMD:" << endl;
    cout << "X:" << C.x << endl;
    cout << "Y:" << C.y << endl;
    cout << "Z:" << C.z << endl;
    cout << "W:" << C.w << endl<<endl;
    cout << "SIMD:" << endl;
    cout << "X:" << D.x << endl;
    cout << "Y:" << D.y << endl;
    cout << "Z:" << D.z << endl;
    cout << "W:" << D.w << endl << endl;

    system("pause");

    return(0);
}
```

It gives me the error:

> Unhandled exception at 0x013A4143 in ASMTest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access
>   violation writing location 0x40800000.

In the + operator, 'l' and 'r' are references in the C++ syntax, but from the inline ASM it treats them just like pointers, right?And MOVAPS takes a pointer and moves 128 bits from it to the given XMM register.I hovered [output] when debugging and it had the correct values post-addition in it.The struct is aligned, so there isn't any problem with using MOVAPS instead of MOVEUPS.

Comment: Can you be more precise as to where the error occurs?

Comment: There must be `MOVAPS output, XMM0` using `masm` syntax, methinks

Comment: @ScottHunter the error occurs right at "return(output);"

qwm shouldn't variables from C++ be enclosed in square brackets?

Comment: @qwm: I don't if inlined assembly differs, but `movaps [output],xmm0` and `movaps output,xmm0` mean the same thing in MASM syntax.

Comment: yeah removing square brackets didn't change anything, however getting rid of the general purpose registers and just doing:   MOVAPS XMM0, l
MOVAPS XMM1, r

caused an error reading invalid pointer address

Comment: @Michael ok, my fault

Comment: @under your code compiles and works fine for me. The problem is most probably absence of `ebx` preservation in your code

Comment: Removing the alignment declspec and using MOVUPS works, so output doesn't get aligned on the stack inside the function?

qwm, so I should find what's in ebx, store it, then restore it after function is done?What about eax?The same?

Comment: Yes, you should store/restore `ebx` (and `esi`, `edi`, `ebp`). No, you can use `eax`, `edx` and `ecx` anyway you want -)